# Verify S3 upload succesfull with md5 in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, md5

I'm uploading a file to S3 with no errors like this:

```
    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        "version" => "latest",
        "region" => $region
    ]);

    $result = $s3->putObject([
        "Bucket" => $bucket,
        "Key" => $key,
        "SourceFile" => $image,
        "ACL" => "public-read"
    ]);
```

I've read about Etags and ContentMD5 headers but I can't seem to put it all together in PHP.

How do know the file contents is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working using the ContentSHA256 key:

```
    $sha256 = hash_file("sha256", $image);
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        "Bucket" => getenv("S3_BUCKET_NAME"),
        "Key" => $key,
        "SourceFile" => $image,
        "ACL" => "public-read",
        "ContentSHA256" => $sha256
    ]);
```

If the SHA doesn't match I get an S3 exception which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Add your file md5 into metadata, to example:

```
$result = $s3->putObject([
    "Bucket" => $bucket,
    "Key" => $key,
    "image" => $image,
    "ACL" => "public-read",
    "Metadata" => [
        "Content-MD5" => base64_encode($fileMd5)
    ]
]);
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata

For getting md5 of file in PHP you can use [md5_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) function

Comment: Used `$md5 = md5_file($image);` 
and added `"ContentMD5" => $md5` as an argument.
Then I get `InvalidDigest (client): The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.` My md5 was `430713ae0317a0f9c15af704c352b95d` but response from server's had `<Content-MD5>430713ae0317a0f9c15af704c352b95d</Content-MD5>`

Comment: Sorry, md5 need to be encoded as base64, I update answer

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is still not working correctly. Now I'm not getting any errors, but I can change my md5 to anything and it still uploads the image without errors :-/

Comment: Use `$md5 = base64_encode(md5_file($path, true));` md5_file need to return binary format.

Answer (score 0):

md5_file need to return binary format

```
$md5base64 = base64_encode(md5_file($path, true));
$result = $s3client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
    'SourceFile' => $image,
    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    'ContentMD5' => $md5base64,
]);
```